# C# Textbox string separation

Tags: c#, string

I have textbox in c#, contains two or three strings with white spaces. i want to store those strings seperately.please, suggest me any code. thanx.

Answer (score 11):

```
var complexValue = @"asdfasdfsdf asdfasd fffff
asdfasdfasdf";
var complexValues = complexValue.Split();
```

**NOTICE:**
`.Split()` is a pseudo-overload, as it gets compiled as `.Split(new char[0])`.
additionally [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) tells us:

> If the separator parameter is
>   null or contains
>   no characters, white-space characters
>   are assumed to be the delimiters.
>   White-space characters are defined by
>   the Unicode standard and return true
>   if they are passed to the
>   `Char.IsWhiteSpace` method.

Comment: ".Split() is a pseudo-overload, as it gets compiled as .Split(new char[0]). " - Nice. I never saw that in the documentation!  Something new every day!

Comment: well ... i, the same as you, saw this overload used by another person and suggested that this ain't a valid overload. then i digged deeper with reflector and ... eye-opener!

Comment: It's an effect of the `params` keyword.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly use this name space

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

in your code

```
 string Message = "hi i am fine";
 string []Record=Regex.Split(Message.Trim(), " ");
```

Output is an array.
I hope it works.

Comment: your example really gives us an impression of how useful `.TrimStart()` and `.TrimEnd()` are... damn ... why not simply use `.Trim()`

Comment: Why would you want to use Regex.Split instead of String.Split??

Comment: I agree it will work with  string [] a= temp.Trim().Split(' ');

Comment: Regex'ing for a single space character is like hitting someone over the head with a tank. Sure it's possible, and it gets the job done, but a beer bottle would have been easier.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] parts = myTextbox.Text.Split();
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) with no parameters will force the method to consume all whitespace and only return the separated strings:

```
var individualStrings = originalString.Split();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get three different strings in an array, you can use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
string[] myStringArray = OriginalString.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
```

Comment: you can write just OriginalString.Split(' ');

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] words =  Regex.Split(textBox.Text, @"\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        string str = @"this is my string";
        string[] arr = str.Split(new char[] { char.Parse(" ") });
```

Comment: hey, why do you use `char.Parse` ...? you could simply use `new char[] { ' ' }` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
    string data = TextBox1.Text;
    var s1 = data.Split();

    string a = s1[0].ToString();
    string  b= s1[1].ToString();
```