# How to convert a string (red,blue,black) to a string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Textbox string separation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726898/c-sharp-textbox-string-separation)

I want to pass the string value ie (red,blue,black) to a string array. I used the following code

```
string[] splitString = myString;
```

I am getting this error

```
Error   137 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'
```

regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] splitString = myString.Split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Split` method of `String` class:

```
myString.Split(',');
```

To have a complete grip over various scenerios, you can visit [.Net Perls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-split)

Comment: @Azodios....I know it but i want the string array for another use..

Comment: @sun could you please explain the issue?

Comment: my doubt is that is it possible to convert a string (ass,dfd,fghfgh)  to a string array?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the `String.Split` method

```
string myString = "red,blue,black";
string[] splitString = myString.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a `string` directly to a `string[]` - this can't work. You need to do something with the string first - the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method looks like a good fit:

```
string[] splitString = "red,blue,black".Split(',');
```

Comment: @Oded...thanks...i got the explanation what i look for...

Comment: @sun if this answer fits your needs, you should declare it as *the* solution

Answer (score 1):

```
string myString = "red,blue,black";

string[] splitString = myString.Split(',');

foreach(string s in splitString)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: @Peter Ivavov...string[] splitString = myString.Split(','); gives Error 137 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]' error

Comment: @sun according to its documentation, `string.Split()` returns `string[]` ... what type is your `myString`? have you tried @PeterIvanov code? and are you really doing `.Split('')` - then the compiler should detect the `params char[]`-overload

Answer (score 1):

Try it like below,

```
        string myString = "red,blue,green";
        string[] splitString = new string[1];
        splitString[0] = myString;
```

or

```
string[] splitString = myString.Split(',');
```

Comment: Ok, so what's your final conclusion to your question?

Answer (score 0):

[string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: ....I know it but i want the string array for another use

Comment: please give way more information! what you are writing ain't clear at all ... give us examples, give us code, give us an idea of what you are trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Or just for an alternative:

```
string myString = "red,blue,black";
var strArr = Regex.Split(myString, ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly you're not trying to split the string, you just need an array with one or more strings, right? In that case you'd do something like this:

```
string[] splitString = new string[]{ "red", "blue", "black" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, you try to assign a type to array of type.

If you declare an array, then you need to initialize it with operator new.

```
String[] arrayOfString = new String[3];
```

In above piece of code you declare a variable `arrayOfString` that is an array of String object. This mean that in arrayOfString you can expect String.

After that you assign to it new array instance for three String objctes (new String[3]), in this step you only reserve memory for three elements.

After this you are able to store any String object in `arrayOfString`.

To store a object in array you just have to use the variable name and indexer.

```
arrayOfString[0] = "StackOverflow";
```

In this example we assign, an String into arryOfString under index 0.

In C# array are indexed from 0 to declared size - 1, that in this case is 2.

Comment: and what's the connection to the OPs question? do you use `string.Split()` anywhere in your answer?

Comment: Where in the question is statement that user want to split anything ? That is only an assumption, based on the array name. The connection with OP question is about why you can not assign String to String[]. Not only the empty solution with split method called on String. If OP would know the difference would ask, how to split a string using a delimiter.